# Validation according to user role

Tags: validation

This is not working according to User role 
any one please suggest

```
AND( 
    OR( 
    $RecordType.Name = "Helpdesk", 
    $RecordType.Name = "Tagged Helpdesk", 
    $UserRole.Name <> "RECO Team" , 
    $UserRole.Name <> "RECO Team Agents"), 

    OR( 
    ISPICKVAL( MHD_Tag__c , "RTO POD"), 
    ISPICKVAL( MHD_Tag__c , "DTO POD")), 
    OR( 
    ISPICKVAL( Return_Type__c ,""), 
    ISPICKVAL(POD_request_status__c ,"")))
```

Comment: Ratan- can you please provide solution

Comment: Can you clarify why you need this to be based on the user role - see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Well for a start putting two "not equals" conditions in an OR statement is always going to return true, which is probably not what you want.

You have

```
 $UserRole.Name <> "RECO Team" OR $UserRole.Name <> "RECO Team Agents"
```

Which means:

if the role name is "RECO Team" then it is <> "RECO Team Agents" so this is TRUE

if the role name is "RECO Team Agents" then it is <> "RECO Team" so this is TRUE

if the role name is anything else then it's still TRUE